# Angular Material : How to validate md-radio-button in a table?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

How do you validate if the md-radio-button hasnt been selected yet? I tried adding div-messages and also div-message but it doesnt seem to work.

```
<table class="table" ng-init="GetQuestionnaires()" ng-model="cd.id">

  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Actions</th>
  </tr>

  <tr class="monster-gray" ng-repeat="q in questionnaireData | filter: search " repeat-complete>
    <td>{{q.Title}}</td>
    <td>{{q.Author.FirstName}}, {{q.Author.LastName}}</td>

    <td> 
      <md-radio-group ng-model="cd.id"  required >
        <md-radio-button value="{{q.Id}}"></md-radio-button>
      </md-radio-group>

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Dear Z.Cook, did my solution helped you?

Answer (score 1):

You can adopt the below solution in the table and it should work fine. I have used in my applications

Check the solution on CodePen (https://codepen.io/jakobadam/pen/xqZoBR)

```
<md-input-container class="md-input-has-value" 
       ng-class="{ 'md-input-invalid' : form.fruit.$invalid && form.$submitted }">
  <label class="md-required" translate>Fruit</label>

  <md-radio-group md-autofocus name="fruit" ng-model="fruit" layout="row" required>
    <md-radio-button value="Apple" class="md-primary">Apple</md-radio-button>
    <md-radio-button value="Banana"> Banana </md-radio-button>
    <md-radio-button value="Mango">Mango</md-radio-button>  
  </md-radio-group>

  <div ng-messages="form.fruit.$error">
    <div ng-message="required" translate>Yo. Select some fruit.</div>
  </div>
</md-input-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve similar by using `ng-required`. Add `ng-required="true"` to on `md-radio-group`, and check before submitting form.

```html
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="$myForm.$valid && vm.submitForm()">
  <md-radio-group ng-model="cd.id" ng-required="true">
    <md-radio-button value="{{q.Id}}"></md-radio-button>
  </md-radio-group>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue. I have several md-button-groups that are required, and I need the user to be alerted that the selection is required. Adding "required" to the md-radio-group works to stop the submit, as does ng-required="true", but I could not get ng-messages to show up. It appears that the Angular Material team is not pursuing the fix for AngularJS, so I made a CSS work around.

This is the HTML:

```
<form class="formClass" name="formName" novalidate ng-submit="formName.$valid && functionToCall()">
    <md-radio-group ng-model="hasAnswer" name="hasAnswer" required>
        <md-radio-button ng-value="true">YES</md-radio-button>
        <md-radio-button ng-value="false">NO</md-radio-button>
    </md-radio-group>
    <md-button type="submit">Submit</md-button>
</form>
```

This is the CSS:

```
.formClass.ng-submitted md-radio-group.ng-pristine::after {
     content: "This is required";
     color: red;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add a form that wraps your `<table>` and wrap your `<md-radio-group>` into an `<md-input-container>`. Your code could look similar to this one:

```
<form name="aForm" novalidate>
  <table>
    ...
    <tr ng-form="trForm" ...>
       <md-input-container>
         <md-radio-group ng-model="cd.id"
                         name="cd"
                         ng-required="true">
           <md-radio-button ng-value="q.Id">
             Select me
          </md-radio-button>
        </md-radio-group>

        <!-- Validation messages -->
        <div ng-show="aForm.submitted" ng-messages="trForm.cd.$error">
          <div ng-message="required">This field is required!</div>
        </div>
      </md-input-container>
```

The `trForm` is needed because you have a `ngRepeat` and you need to validate against one row instead of the whole form.